# Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob' ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Guys why does it show me this error when I try to upload a PDF file "Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'":

```
function Test() {

const [file, setFile] = useState()

const SubmitFile = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const formdata = new FormData()
    try {
        formdata.append(
            'file',
            file,
            file.name,
        )
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/upload", formdata,{
            headers:{
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}
return (
<div>
    <h1>File upload</h1>
    <form onSubmit={SubmitFile}>
        <input onChange={(e)=>{setFile(e.target.files)}} accept="application/pdf" type= 
{"file"} id='file' />
        <input type={"submit"} value="submit" />
    </form>

</div>
)
}
export default Test
```

Comment: `e.target.files` is an array-ish object (a [`FileList`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section), to be exact), not a single file.

Comment: So what can i do?

Comment: …iterate it? Or since you don’t accept multiple files, just obtain element zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change into this:

```
 let formdata = new FormData()
    try {
        formdata.append(
            'file',
            file[0],
            file.name,
        )
```

Comment: You also need to index the array to extract the file name. But yes, that’s pretty much it.